# Mutex lock on fd returned by accept

Tags: sockets, server, locking, client, mutual-exclusion

I have a client/server application implemented with a thread pool of worker.
In server's main I create a listener socket and then for each client I get a fd with accept() to handle client's requests.
My question is: do I need a lock on this fd to read client's requests and to write the answers and data?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Listener sockets are coordination points, you don't need to explicitly coordinate.   It's not even clear what "locking" a socket means; sockets don't "lock".   They may or my not "block" depending on how they are configured - and this will determine if your operations return immediately, after a given timeout, or wait indefinitely to complete.

When you `accept()` on a listen socket successfully, the result is a second socket - this is the one that you use to communicate with the client, not the listener socket.

Of course if your application is multi-threaded, your /threads/ may need to lock or mutex to get proper behavior.  Details will vary depending on your actual design and how socket IO states interact with threads can get very complicated / prickly.   You'd need to post code for more concrete answers.

There are many more details to even single-threaded socket IO.   See https://cis.temple.edu/~giorgio/old/cis307s96/readings/docs/sockets.html

Comment: I meant if it was necessary a lock on the second socket when I use it to communicate with the client, not on the listen socket. Thank you for the link.